# Better way of clone and then replace some attributes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have HTML code like this :

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" id="addTxt">Add Text</a>
<div id="nF">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-text-width"></i>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" id="project_components_attributes_32943600_name" name="project[components_attributes][32943600][name]" type="text">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <input id="project_components_attributes_32943600__destroy" name="project[components_attributes][32943600][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false">
              <a class="btn btn-default" data-selector="removeField" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
              </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click link "Add Text", It will clone `div` with class `form-inline` and append to `div#nF` and then replacing all attribute of `input` tag in `form-inline` (`id` and `name`) with new value from new date and time.

For Illustration :

> id => project_components_attributes_32943600_name => replace
>   "32943600" with new value
>
> name => project[components_attributes][32943600][_destroy] => replace
>   "32943600" with new value

And this javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addTxt').click(function(){
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        var $target = $('#nF').find('div.form-inline:first');
        $target.clone().appendTo('#nF');
        $target.find('input').each(function(){           
           $(this).val('');
           var tID = $(this).attr("id").split(/_/);
           var re = new RegExp(tID[3],"g");
           var newID = $(this).attr('id').replace(re, time);
           var newName = $(this).attr('name').replace(re, time);
           $(this).attr('id', newID);
           $(this).attr('name', newName);
        });
    });
});
```

Live Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/gjj8mzya/

Is there any way to clone element and replace attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current code does essentially this:

1. Clone the dirtied first item and append to the end
2. Modify the dirtied first item to make it clean again

It would be better to use a clean prototype / template from which you can easily create clean new instances. Then the operations can become:

1. Move the dirtied first item to the end
2. Recreate the first item from the clean template

The first approach is not so good, because:

- Cloning is always a suspicious operation. For example, you have to make sure that:

  - all fields correctly copied
  - no references accidentally leaked
  - deep objects correctly deep-copied: although this is not a concern in this specific example, but I'm adding it anyway as a reminder of general concerns about the concept of cloning
- Reseting an object to a clean state is always a suspicious operation. For example, you have to make sure that:

  - all fields are correctly reset: often duplicating the same logic that must exist (explicitly or implicitly) in the initializer / constructor

The new approach doesn't have any of these tricky issues.
It's conceptually much cleaner, with much fewer hidden traps and bugs waiting to happen.